# Arithmetic progressions in arrays with limited range

Tags: algorithms, computational-complexity, arithmetic-progressions, fast-fourier-transform

It is known that [finding 3 evenly spaced ones](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1560523/onlogn-algorithm-find-three-evenly-spaced-ones-within-binary-string) and [3SUM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3SUM) applied to (sorted) arrays with elements in the range $[0, \dots, N]$ can be solved in $\mathcal{O}(n + N \log N)$ time. Methods for solving either of the problems are based on convolution of polynomials (using the DFT).

Similarly, $k$-SUM with limited inputs can be solved in $\mathcal O(2^{\lfloor (k+1)/2 \rfloor} N k\log N)$ time due to an increase in DFT size (for a non-fourier approach of $k$-SUM, see [this](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/2973/generalised-3sum-k-sum-problem)).

Now, I generalize the question "finding 3 evenly spaced ones" to finding [arithmetic progressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression), finding one of length $k$ (or verifying it exists) generally has time complexity $\mathcal O(n^2 k)$. But with input $< N$ and $k=3$ we get $\mathcal O(n + N \log N)$ as it can be reduced to 3SUM.

**My question:** Is there any known (or unknown) method to verify/find an arithmetic progression of any length $k>3$ in under quadratic time? You may use that the input is sorted, in a small range and does not contain any duplicates.

Any help would be much appreciated! I have spend a long time trying to figure this out without being able to think of a type of transform or method to enable this (or make it easier).

Comment: Still asking in $[0,..,N]$?

Comment: @kodlu, yes. And non-quadratic algorithms in $N$ are asked ($n$ is also fine but more difficult).